# page loaded differently with jQuery-mobile transition

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a site that works fine when loaded directly (f.e. by calling its URL), however, when I get to the site through a slider transition:

```
<li><a href="html/mySite.html" data-transition="slide">mySite</a></li>
```

it seems as if it would not load a .js file which is just declared within head as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../myJS.js"></script>
```

I am new to jQuery mobile, and jQuery, and HTML5, and JS. So... can someone explain to me what is the difference between a URL call and a jQuery mobile transtition regarding to the loading of the page?

(btw. I am using it to develop an Android-App)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case of multiple **`HTML`** files, **`HEAD`** is only loaded in the first **`HTML`** file. In other files, only a **`BODY`** content is loaded. This is because **`AJAX`** is used to load other pages into the **`DOM`**. Because there's already a **`HEAD`** content inside an original **`DOM`** only a body will be loaded from the other pages.

This can be prevented if you turn **`AJAX`** loading completely, or if you initialize all of your js fils inside a first **`HTML`** file.

If you want to find out more take a look at my other **[ANSWER](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)** with several other solutions, or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800121/why-i-have-to-put-all-the-script-to-index-html-in-jquery-mobile/15806954#15806954)**.

### Example 1: Correct way

**HTML 1 :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
              $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
                        alert('Page One');
                });
                
                $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function(){       
                        alert('Page Two');                  
                });         
    </script>      
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="second.html" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML 2 :**

```
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
            <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>
```

### Example 2: Incorrect way

**HTML 1 :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
              $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
                        alert('Page One');
                });     
    </script>      
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="second.html" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML 2 :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
                $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function(){       
                        alert('Page Two');                  
                }); 
        </script>         
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>    
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
            <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will the Head of the first HTML be used for all other pages? can I just load my JS at the first site?

Comment: First HTMl head is going to be used for all other pages.

Comment: Unless you turn ajax off, in that case every page change will load tha page normally but you will not have transition effects. So initialize all of your js files inside a first HTML HEAD. You can even test it if you create a small example.

Comment: why is there `<script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>` on page 2 if it will not be loaded? or are there some exceptions?

Comment: It is there just to show you the difference between example 1 and example 2. I will remove it, and everything will still work correctly.

Comment: It seems to at least read the meta tags. If I do not add `<meta charset="utf-8" />` I get unknown symbols (I am using 'ü')