# Mobiscroll plugin in jquery mobile dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

Is it possible to use [Date & Time Scroller](http://mobiscroll.com/component/datetime) plugin with [jQuery Mobile Dialog](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/dialog/) widget? The problem is that dialog widget parses data from other page in `<div data-role="page" id="page">` and js files, which are included in the header are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at an answer I gave few minutes ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15431229/1848600

Your problem is not in Mobiscroll implementation or a jQuery Mobile Dialog widget. If you are loading a dialog widget form the other file it will act like a normal page. jQuery Mobile will load ONLY its BODY content, and the rest si going to be discarded. To fix this, all js code intended for the dialog should be loaded inside a first HTML file.

Comment: yes, already understood it by myself, but thanks for response.