# Jquery Mobile : slide transition

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button with slide transition hyperlink.

```
<a href="register.html" data-transition="slide"><img src="images/enter_btn.png"  width="82" height="82" /></a>
```

While the page slide to `register.html`, in ready function, I have added a log text to check.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 console.log('here');
});
```

But above code is not printing the text. When I reload the page again, it prints the log text. Why is that?? Help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Slide Property which is you are using is only for slide purpose, in this situation your DOM is  not reload. So you have put your code on onclick function of that `a` tag.

Comment: without document ready on register.html, how can i use onclick function?

Comment: you can add JS in your Head of HTML, and put your code over in that JS file.

Comment: $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#register', function(){       
                        alert('Page One');
                });

Comment: Like above way you can call. or else i dont know what you are doing because i dont have your code.

Comment: Refer this question :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430912/page-loaded-differently-with-jquery-mobile-transition

Comment: Thanks for the link.."In case of multiple HTML files, HEAD is only loaded in the first HTML file. In other files, only a BODY content is loaded. This is because AJAX is used to load other pages into the DOM. Because there's already a HEAD content inside an original DOM only a body will be loaded from the other pages." === i have added my js inside body and it works

Comment: @stupid If you got the solution then kindly mark it as helpful answer.